# A DB2 Trigger to UPDATE to update a newly added row

Tags: triggers, db2

I need to create a DB2 trigger that only updates the newly added rows based on the values entered.

I have a DB2 table "documents" with the following fields

```
docnumber = a number created by an app,
unique_parent = NULL,
unique_child = NULL
```

3. I have to get something like this

```
docnumber = number created by app,
unique_parent = XX-(docnumber value),
unique_child = XX-(docnumber value)-(random number)
```

For example

1. The user inserts two rows

```
docnumber="0123", unique_parent=NULL, unique_child=NULL
docnumber="4567", unique_parent=NULL, unique_child=NULL
```

2. On insert the trigger should update the "unique_parent" and "unique_child" fields **only in the two rows added** in this way

```
unique_parent="XX-(docnumber value)"
unique_child="XX-(docnumber value)-(random number)"
```

3. The result should be something like this

```
docnumber="0123", unique_parent="XX-0123", unique_child="XX-0123-879" (879 is random)
docnumber="4567", unique_parent="XX-4567", unique_child="XX-4567-574" (574 is random)
```

Does this trigger work?

```
CREATE TRIGGER ADD_UNIQUE_VALUES
AFTER INSERT ON documents
UPDATE documents
SET unique_parent = CONCAT('XX-', docnumber),
unique_child = CONCAT(
    CONCAT('XX-', docnumber),
    CONCAT('-', INT(RAND(1) * 100000000) )
)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you want to consider a `before` trigger instead.

Comment: Something like this?

CREATE TRIGGER ADD_UNIQUE_VALUES
NO CASCADE BEFORE INSERT ON documents
REFERENCING NEW AS N
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
SET N.unique_parent = CONCAT('XX-', N.docnumber);
SET N.unique_child = CONCAT(
        CONCAT('XX-', N.docnumber),
        CONCAT('-', INT(RAND(1) * 100000000) )
    );
END